# App size: Xamarin Forms vs Xamarin Native

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is there a difference in app size between xamarin forms and xamarin native?

I did not find an answer to this on the internet despite my many searches. Thank you!

Comment: hard to tell and probably undecided, since we have the proguard linker-optimizer, AOT/LLVM etc. try it! depends on so many factors apart from just that.

Comment: Yes, obviously there is a difference, an obvious example of why would be the XF package itself which is an extra package in all of your projects. Not to mention when you create XF projects and try to use certain functionality directly in a cross-platform manner you tend to use existing Nuget packages for them which again will increase your final bundle size. At the long run with optimizations and stuff, it could be somewhere around 10-15mbs heavier based on the amount of functionality you intend to add to it and the scope of your project.

Comment: One way to save some memory would be to write your own code for every functionality and try to avoid using packages wherever natively achievable but that would sustainably increase development time and might create tough scenarios if you are not familiar with the XF patterns for integrating native functionalities. Not to mention even developers familiar with XF and Xamarin, in general, get stuck on such issues.